# One To Many relationship data seeding in .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm having trouble seeding data to my database at `OnModelCreating` method.

I want to seed my database with **Countries**, **States** and **Cities** but I don't know how to do it when they have *one-to-many* relationships.

**Models:**

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

**Context:**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ....
        modelBuilder.Entity<State>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Cities)
            .WithOne(c => c.State)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .HasMany(s => s.States)
            .WithOne(s => s.Country)
            .IsRequired();

        var BsAs = new State
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Buenos Aires",
        };

        var Argentina = new Country
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Argentina",
            States = new[] { BsAs }
        };

        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>(s => {
            s.HasData(Argentina);
            s.OwnsMany(e => e.States).HasData(BsAs);
        });
    }
```

The code above throws:

> The type 'State' cannot be marked as owned because a non-owned entity type with the same name already exists.

when I try to **AddMigration**.

My goal is to seed the database with one country and its respecting states and cities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Getting Started with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli#create-the-model) and [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) pages have a good example of one-to-many mapping.

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

In your case a `City` needs to have `StateId` and a `State` needs to have `CountryId`.

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    (...)
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   (...)
   public int CountryId { get; set; }
   public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

---

EF Core's [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) contains an example of seeding data for one-to-many relationship model.

> ```
> modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasData(new Blog {BlogId = 1, Url = "http://sample.com"});
>
> modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasData(
>     new Post() { BlogId = 1, PostId = 1, Title = "First post", Content = "Test 1" });
> ```